# Rails 3.1, paperclip, s3 - uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am getting the following error when trying to upload an image using paperclip and s3 storage. The app worked fine uploading locally, but when I've made the required changes to use s3 I get the following:

> NameError in ImagesController#create
>
> uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Base

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'dynamic_form'
end

gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'paperclip'
```

models/Image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :file, 
                      :styles => {
                          :featured => "970x560>", 
                          :thumb => "192x112>" 
                      },
                      :storage => :s3,
                      :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/amazon_s3.yml"
end
```

config/amazon_s3.yml

```
bucket: myapp-dev
access_key_id: ####################
secret_access_key: ################################
```

Bundled gems:
aws-sdk (1.2.5)
paperclip (2.4.5) 
rails (3.1.3)

Comment: You probably need to `include AWS::S3` somewhere.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Paperclip 2.4.5 still uses the `aws-s3` gem. (The README on Github refers to `aws-sdk`, but that's only for the unreleased master branch).

Change your Gemfile line to:

```
gem "aws-s3", :require => "aws/s3"
```

or use the master branch instead of the stable version (which of course has some risk involved):

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem "aws-sdk"
```

**UPDATE**: Paperclip 2.5.0, released on 1/13/2012, now uses `aws-sdk`.

Comment: does this mean that we need to remove the line `gem "aws-s3", :require => "aws/s3"` from the gem file?

Comment: @Paarth With Paperclip >= 2.5.0, you no longer need the aws-s3 gem (it uses aws-sdk now). I don't know if leaving the aws-s3 gem in your Gemfile will cause any conflicts, though.

Comment: @Markow Thanks for quick reply, i will try and let you know. I am facing issue while upgrading my ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3. Please have a look @ [PaperClip not working while upgrading to 1.9.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147038/ruby-with-paperclip-upgrading-1-8-7-to-1-9-3-paperclip-s3-upload-not-working)

Comment: @Markow, it worked without aws-s3 as you mentioned, but the problem i was facing is because of contentType config for paperclip model. Please check the link i mentioned in prev. comment for the resolution.

Answer (score -2):

whomever decided to kill paperclip to windows user did a good job.

bundle install

```
Fetching git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
remote: Counting objects: 5602, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2419/2419), done.
remote: Total 5602 (delta 3868), reused 4704 (delta 3065)
Receiving objects: 100% (5602/5602), 855.88 KiB | 314 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3868/3868), done.
error: unable to create file test/fixtures/question?mark.png (Invalid argument)
```

so checking out gem 'paperclip', :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git" directly does not solve the issue.
gem "aws-s3", :require => "aws/s3" solves the issue for now but it probably means no update to the 2.5.0 for now